# Run audio file when new enquiry is received PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

We have a website where we receive enquiries  for products which we sell online.

When a New enquiry is received to the support employee I want to run a audio file which alerts the person that a new enquiry got assigned to them.

The admin module works in PHP & MySQL.

The enquiry Table columns is as given below

```
  Enquiry_Id    |    EnqName  |  EnqEmail   |   Created_On   |   Attended_Status
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And exactly how are you planning for the webserver to be able to reach out to this employee to play the file on their browser? Going to use long-polling? comet? websockets? Better figure that out, after which the rest of the mechanics of actually playing the audio will be the easiest of it all.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an AJAX script that runs periodically (let's say every minute) that

- checks the status of the database: says whether a new order has come in the mean time
- plays the audio file like nageeb suggested.

This assumes that employee has got a page that's always on.

If you give us more information I can update this.

Comment: use long polling instead of checking every minute. Or something more efficient. Periodic checking is now old school.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the php email function, so when you insert the row into the DB, lookup the representatives email and email him to notify him. (The email program can play an audio clip).

Comment: The email  notification is already there we want laptops to make some sound which tells the support that new enquiry is received even when they are not at the system

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a quick solution, and not knowing too much about the structure of your application, this may or may not work...

- I assume that there is probably some sort of page which lists the existing enquiries on your site that the representatives simply leave open... If so, set it to refresh every 5m or so.
- In the for() loop that generates the list of enquiries, make sure that you have a column that would identify an enquiry as being "new" (perhaps the Attended_Status field?).
- Put an if() statement in the for() loop and check for whatever would define a new enquiry, and if it resolves to true, just echo something like this: `<object height="1" width="1" data="some_alert.mp3"></object>` which should generate a 1x1 (essentially invisible) mp3 player  based on whatever default audio player is installed on the user's computer.

It's the quickest/easiest way I can think of, as I said above, not knowing too much about your app.